# Laravel Controller does not exist, but actually it does

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-controller

I have some problem with the controller. In my local repo as I `serve` the project it works!
route: at `web.php` `Route::get('/jobs', 'one\jobs\JobsController@index');` But as I tried at my company's server it didn't work! **It says controller does not exist.** I've compared the controller and web route but it is the same with my local one.

And here is my controller:

> App\Http\Controllers\one\Jobs\JobsController;

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\one\Jobs;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Library\One\ApiLibrary;
    use Alert;
    
    class JobsController extends Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->apiLib = new ApiLibrary;
        }
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $token = $request->session()->get('token');
            $put['data'] = ['token' => $token];
            
            $this->apiLib->setParams($put['data']);
            $result = $this->apiLib->generate('GET','/api/jobs');
            
            if(!empty($result->status))
            {
                $data = $result->data;
                $action = $result->action->original;
    
                return view('one.jobs.jobsList',compact('data', 'action'));
            }else{
                $err_messages = "Server Error"; 
                return view('one.errors.errors', compact('err_messages'));
            }
        }
    }
```

got any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have referenced your controller is wrong:

```
Route::get('/jobs', 'one\jobs\JobsController@index');
```

Should be:

```
Route::get('/jobs', 'one\Jobs\JobsController@index');
```

You used a capital `J` in your controller `namespace` but a lowercase `j` when referencing it in your `web.php`. These things are case sensitive and should match the naming of files and folders for `psr-4` autoloading.

Comment: I tried, and it works!! thanks @Peppermintology